# Enter VR in A-Frame not working in Wolvic browser on Oculus Quest

Tags: aframe, oculus, webvr

[A-Frame](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/vr-mode-ui.html) by default provides the "enter VR" button at the bottom right of the screen. This is working fine on my desktop, and also in Firefox Reality on my Oculus Quest. But in Wolvic, instead of opening in the VR mode, I see 2 views/screens.

I got the same behaviour for several examples on glitch.com, this is 1 example: [https://glitch.com/~aframe-vaporwave](https://glitch.com/%7Eaframe-vaporwave)

Any idea what's causing this and/or how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The example you pointed out uses a very old version of A-Frame (0.5.0) based on the old WebVR API that browsers no longer ship. Make sure you're using 1.3.0 or newer that comes with WebXR support.

All the A-Frame examples should work on Wolvic:

https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/

Can also use the official glitch A-Frame support as starting point:

[https://glitch.com/~aframe](https://glitch.com/%7Eaframe)